# How to deploy solidity smart contract at multiple addresses programmatically?

Tags: nodes, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Can someone please tell me how one can deploy a smart contract to multiple addresses, instead of one ethereum address? For example, I have a smart contract in solidity named ExampleContract. I would like to deploy the same smart contract programmatically to different ethereum addresses.
Please help me here.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can programmatically do this. Ethereum contract address depends on address of its creator and nonce (amount of  transactions the creator has sent). So you just should different nonce, addresses can be precalculated.
you can find more information [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/cli/2.8/deploying-with-create2)